# Capturing 'this' in Nancy Lambda Capture

Tags: c#, lambda, nancy

I have a Nancy module that looks something like this

```
public class Configurer : NancyModule
{
    private Settings mSettings;

    public Configurer()
    {
        mSettings = new Settings();

        Get["/"] = parameters =>
        {
            // Do something with mSettings here
            mSettings.Name = new string("blah");
            // and then return a response
            return Response.AsJson<Settings>(mSettings);.
        };
    }
}
```

The issue I am having is that `mSettings` is always `null`(I am assuming because I am not capturing `this` in the lamdba closure. I have tried passing this in the closure but it does not work). I have also tried using the paramaters dynamic dictionary but that also failed. Is it possible to use member variables in a nancy module and if so how can it be done? I am probably missing something obvious!

No exceptions are being thrown regarding the creation of settings etc. and I can use it elsewhere in the class, just not in the Lambdas. The class is also thread safe, I just didn't add it to the example above.

Comment: Is this the only time you are assigning a value to the `mSettings` field?

Comment: @Dirk In the actual code mSettings is only really being read in the GET, its settings are populated elsewhere however they are accessed in other places in the class and the values are as expected. The class is thread safe so its not a data race as far as I can tell. Any member variable of the class is null or default when I try to access from the GET. Hence why I assume its to do with capturing 'this'

Comment: @BenJ Not sure how that would help. The above scenario is naive in that it creates a local copy of the object. The real code gathers the info from elsewhere in the constructor and then creates the copy of the object. I therefore cant pass the settings as an argument as member settings is null(according to the GET)

Comment: There is no problem capturing `mSettings`. If it is `null` inside the lambda expression then it is either never assigned a value or `null` has been assigned to it. You could check whether you accidently assign another value to it by making the field `readonly`, that way only the constructor can write to it and you get compile-time errors if other methods try to do that.

Comment: @Dirk I have just tested what you said and I agree. The issue seems to be because it is re-assigned in another function, which seems to turn it to null in the GET. Any ideas?

Comment: Keep in mind you capture the *variable* not the *value of the variable*. When you later assign `null` to it the value of `mSettings` in the lambda expression will be `null` too. If you don't want to capture the `mSettings` field then use a local variable instead.

Comment: I didnt assign null, the object is still valid elsewhere, it is only in the GET that it is seemingly null

Comment: Could you show the other code which which uses `Configurer`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I have figured out that Nancy Modules are reconstructed on every call i.e. they cannot keep state information. I will have to maintain state somewhere else and call into it when needed. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: I suggest you post it as answer, so other people who might run into this know what to do.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Have done so now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that on every call to a Nancy route(GET etc.) a new version of the Nancy module is constructed. Therefore the lifetime is only as long as that single call. That means that any member variables have to be constructed in the constructor before the Nancy routes are defined.

The downside of this is that you cannot modify or keep state elsewhere in the class. Therefore it is necessary to keep the state information elsewhere and provide an interface to retrieve it from the Nancy module.

The example above would work as expected(therefore not the best example) however in my real use case `mSettings` was populated elsewhere in the class in another method and was only read in the Nancy routes by which time the state is invalid.